# How to make a pop to appear gradually using jquery and bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is after a user has signed up, then it will redirect that user to another page that is a profile page. On profile page, I want to make a pop up screen gradually appear so that user could enter an email or something.

I know how to make a modal appear in bootstrap, but how to make it appear gradually?

Comment: What do you mean by gradually?  Bootstrap modals already have a transition on them.

Comment: For example, like when user is on profile page, i want to trigger that modal. How would i do that? How do i call a modal using jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger a modal with JQuery in the following way.

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Just put it in your `$(document).ready(....);` if you want it to show immediately on page load.